# Wav files voice to Text

Tags: .net, scripting, speech-to-text

Is there a library that I could use in either a script or a .Net project that does Voice to text?

I have a directory full of voice prompts for dozens of customers and multiple accounts under each customer.  I want to be able to pull the text from as many of them as I can without human interaction.

I've played with Dragon Dictate... But it's too manual.  I need to be able to script SOMETHING.

Comment: Like OCR, it's very difficult to do speech-to-text and get it right, especially if the speech is human.  Dragon is on version 11+ and it still makes mistakes even when you train it well.  It would be easier if the voice prompts were created by computer voice from a text file (then you wouldn't have to do this at all).

Comment: It would be easier if the knuckleheads who had them recorded saved the verbiage as documentation...

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to use System.Speech and the namespaces under that, particularly [System.Speech.Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx).

Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may try Voicebase services.
http://voicebase.readthedocs.io/en/v2-beta/